# Monopoly Deal - property wild card queries

Tags: monopoly-deal

A completed set using one or two property wild card with a house and hotel.

Can we move property wild card to another set in such scenario?

Can we move house or hotel to another completed set?

Answer (score 2):

**In answer to the first part of your question:** we have always played that you can't move a card from a stack with a house/hotel expect to pay another player. However, I can't seem to find a rule written down that says this.

**For the second part of the question:** my initial assumption was that you can't do this. However, the rules say you can rearrange your cards in any way you choose **during your turn**. It is worth reading the section below from monopolydealrules.com who are usually very good and as close to an official rules site as the game has:

> Can a House or Hotel card be on the table without being apart of a full/completed set?
>
> Yes, but you cannot lay down a House or Hotel card unless you can play
>   it on a completed set. However, if a player charges you money and you
>   decide to pay with some of the property from your completed set that
>   includes a House and/or Hotel, the House or Hotel must be placed on
>   the table next to your property section until you complete another set
>   and it can be placed on top. You can also pay with your house or hotel
>   card if you choose.

I hope this answer helps and if anyone has a better answer I'd be very happy to be corrected!